# getServerSideProps doesn't work redirect for all pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I wan't for all pages if I has not token then redirect to /login

in _app,js file I added

```
  export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
      return {
        props: {},
        redirect: { destination: "/login" },
      };
    }
```

Then I run npm run build and start but getServerSideProps  redirect dont wok for any pages

Maybe I created incorrect build not in
prod mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `getServerSideProps` is not supported in `_app` file right now. You can check [this document](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) for the reference.

But we can achieve the same thing with `getInitialProps`

```
App.getInitialProps = (ctx) => {
    //TODO: Check authenticated value in cookies or somewhere in your code
    const isAuthenticated = false

    if(!isAuthenticated) {
      if(typeof window === 'undefined'){ //server-side rendering
        res.redirect('/login')
        res.end()
        return {}
      } else { //client-side rendering
        Router.push('/login')
        return {}
      }
    }
    
    return {
       props: {}
    }
}
```

Following [this document](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app#caveats) again

> Adding a custom getInitialProps in your App will disable [Automatic Static Optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization) in pages without Static Generation.

You need to consider this trade-off too.

If you want to handle it without these side effects. I'd suggest you use [`Context API`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Your `_app.js` may be like this

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return <AuthenticationProvider>
     <Component {...pageProps}/>
  </AuthenticationProvider>
}
```

After that, you can do some redirection stuff inside `AuthenticationProvider` that will apply to all pages

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use this for hard coding the "/login" you can easily write it in your component, the point of the getServerSideProps function is to fetch data from the backend and preload the data